# Is there a way to merge / update result rows in Views with AJAX rather than the default which replaces the whole view div?

Tags: ajax, views

In a view with *Use AJAX:Yes* we see that upon filtering we get a completely new set of results and the `div.view` is completely replaced.

Is there a way to merge rows rather than replace all rows? i.e. - if we have 10 items, and after filtering we see that we have only 3 new items to be displayed, we remove the 3 that are no longer applicable and append the 3 new items.